# Проверка на тип данных, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, числа

Не подскажите, как проверить тип данных который вводит юзер ? Если он вводит например вместо числа - букву, чтобы вопрос о вводе повторялся еще раз, и значение в переменную не записывалось.

```
def handle_start(message):
    user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
    user_markup.row('c')
    user_markup.row('/restart')
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Hello, i`m bot ', reply_markup=user_markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, func_0)


def func_0(message):
    user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
    user_markup.row('B', 'L')
    user_markup.row('/restart')
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'your letter ? ', reply_markup=user_markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, func_1)


def func_1(message):
    user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
    user_markup.row('9', '3')
    user_markup.row('/restart')
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'your digit ? ', reply_markup=user_markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, func_2)
    n = message.text
    user_list['n'] = n
```

Заранее благодарю

Comment: Посмотрите о функции `type` для определения типа обьекта

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас есть строка с числом:

```
n = message.text
```

Есть разные варианты проверки, например:

- Через строковой метод [isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

  ```
  is_num = n.isdigit()
  ```

  Есть и другие методы, например [isdecimal()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal), но тот поддерживает [специфические представления числа](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), поэтому не думаю, что для вашей задачи это нужно.
- Через приведение к числу используя `int`:

  ```
  is_num = True
  try:
      int(n)
  except ValueError:
      is_num = False
  ```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @nikkole.nickell, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Но вы можете подождать, возможно кто-то еще добавит свой вариант ответа -- есть и другие способы проверки